# Android fail to build when add Firebase Analytics

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to add `firebase-analytics:17.4.4` to my project with this `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*************"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2")
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.javadev:underscore:1.55'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

The problem that when i try to build the project i get this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-26:19 to override.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Analytics 17.0.0+ uses AndroidX. So you'll have to [migrate your app to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to use it.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17